# variable undefined using jquery; possible format conflict

Tags: jquery, coldfusion-10

Need a little help with this. Seems pretty simple but I must be missing something. I am trying to retrieve some id values when clicking an anchor tag. For some reason I am not getting all the values. I am thinking there is a conflict with the format of the data. Here is the code

**jquery**

*EDITED to reflect Jai's recomendation - same results*

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 

  // find value of id and name
  $j(".dig").on("click", function(e) {
        var scheduleID = ($j(this).attr('id'));
            console.log(scheduleID);
        var scheduleTime = ($j(this).closest("div").attr('id'));
            console.log(scheduleTime);
        var scheduleDay = ($j(this).closest("li").attr('id'));
            console.log(scheduleDay);
        var day, times;
      $j( "#show-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        $j("#scheduleID").val(scheduleID);   
        $j("#scheduleTime").val(scheduleTime);        
        $j("#scheduleDay").val(scheduleDay);   
            day     =  $j("#scheduleDay").val();
            times   =  $j("#scheduleTime").val();
        $j('#scheduleWarning').html('<p>NOTE: if you upload an MP3 file for your episode below, it will be put into the ' + day + ' ' + times + ' programming slot. Be sure to select ' + day + ' ' + times + ' to sync this episode with your audio file</p>');
     });
```

**html**

```
<li id="Monday">
    <div id="#x#:00" class="time">
        <a id="#ID#" class="icon icon-primary material-icons-backup icon-sm icon-backup dig" style="cursor:pointer" title="upload show"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Monday #x#:00
    </div>
</li>
```

So... the console is showing all three id's from the html but the #scheduleWarning html output is not showing the "times" var value. It is saying it is *undefined*.

The variable #x# is an index value produced by Coldfusion from a database query. An example of what is produced is as follows.

```
 <div id="21:00" class="time">
```

Any idea why the "times" var is showing up *undefined*?

Just a little tidbit of my debugging results. IF I change

```
$j("#scheduleDay").val(scheduleDay);
```

to

```
$j("#scheduleDay").val(scheduleTime);
```

the "day" var shows the correct value of the

```
var scheduleTime = ($j(this).closest("div").attr('id'));
```

I hope I didn't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 2):

That happens to be called variable ***hoisting***. When you declare any variable it is hoisted at the top by the javascript compiler. So, at that point of time the value is `undefined` due to its not set. Instead you can do this:

```js
$j(document).ready(function() {
  // find value of id and name
  $j(".dig").on("click", function(e) {
    var scheduleID = ($j(this).attr('id'));
    var scheduleTime = ($j(this).closest("div").attr('id'));
    var scheduleDay = ($j(this).closest("li").attr('id'));
    var day, times; // <--------------------------------declare it here.

    $j("#show-form").dialog("open");
    $j("#scheduleID").val(scheduleID);
    $j("#scheduleTime").val(scheduleTime);
    $j("#scheduleDay").val(scheduleDay);
    day = $j("#scheduleDay").val();
    times = $j("#scheduleTime").val();
    $j('#scheduleWarning').html('<p>NOTE: if you upload an MP3 file for your episode below, it will be put into the ' + day + ' ' + times + ' programming slot. Be sure to select ' + day + ' ' + times + ' to sync this episode with your audio file</p>');
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried the code as you have displayed here with the console code and without. With console code added, I am seeing it in the console. I am still getting undefined.

Comment: If I change "times  =  $j("#scheduleTime").val();" to "times  =  $j("#scheduleID").val();" the "times" var shows the id correctly. There has to be something wrong with the formatting of the time. It shows up in the console but still shows "undefined".